# Dynamic html output using <% %>

Tags: asp.net

I have a page which can be in English or Swedish. The page contains a lot of phone numbers. What I want to do is show phone numbers as 0XX XXX XXX when in Swedish mode, and +46(0)XX XXX XXX when in English mode.

I'm not too keen on using unique asp.net-controls for each and every phone number as they are quite a few. What I'm thinking is using <% Phone(); %>. Problem is nothing gets outputed. The debugger does however run the Phone method. Any ideas/recommendations? Can <%%> only be used in conjunction with data controls?

Code:

```
<strong>Phone:</strong> <%Phone(); %>418 43 30 30<br>

public string Phone()
{
    if (Session["lang"].ToString() == "SE")
        return "0";
    return "+46(0)";
}
```

Comment: Do these phone numbers come from something like a list of objects on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - `<%=Phone(); %>`. You need `=` in order for the return value to be placed within HTML code.

Comment: Better use `<%:%>` if on .NET 4.0 or above, as it adds HTML encoding.

Comment: So awesomely simple. Thank you